# C# - Remove an item for a Linked List

Tags: c#, list

OK I'm having a problem, I just can't seem to get this to work, no matter what I try. The problem is everytime I write to Console I get an error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'

However, there is no boolean data from what I can see, bar the conditions.

```
    class Link
{
    private int data;
    private Link next;

    public Link(int item) //constructor with an item
    {
        data = item;
        next = null;
    }
    public Link(int item, Link list) //constructor with item and list
    {
        data = item;
        next = list;
    }

    public int Data //property for data
    {
        set { this.data = value; }
        get { return this.data; }
    }

    public Link Next //property for next
    {
        set { this.next = value; }
        get { return this.next;}
    }

}
```

}

All my other methods work i.e. Display item, count the number of items etc. But what seems to be the problem:

```
class LinkList
{
    private Link list = null; //default value – empty list

    public void AddItem(int item) //add item to front of list
    {
        list = new Link(item, list);
    }

    public string DisplayItems() //write items to string and return
    {
        Link temp = list;
        string buffer = "";
        while (temp != null) // move one link and add head to the buffer
        {
            buffer += temp.Data + "";
            temp = temp.Next;
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    public int NumberOfItems() // returns number of items in list
    {
        Link temp = list;
        int count = 0;
        while (temp != null) // move one link and add 1 to count
        {
            count++;
            temp = temp.Next;
        }
        return count;
    }



    public void RemoveItem(int item)
    {
        Link current = list;
        Link previous = null;

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.Data == item)
            {
                if (previous != null)
                {

                    previous.Next = current.Next;
                    current = current.Next;

                }


                else
                {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.Next;
                    list = current;
                }
            }
            else
                previous = current;
               current= current.Next;
        }

    }





    public bool IsPresent(int item)
    {
        Link temp = list;
        bool result = false;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            if (temp.Data == item)
            {
                result = true;
                break;

            }

            else
            {
                temp = temp.Next;

            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

This is my program class I use to print to console-

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinkList testList = new LinkList();
        testList.AddItem(10);
        testList.AddItem(20);
        testList.AddItem(30);
        testList.AddItem(40);
        testList.AddItem(50);
        testList.AddItem(60);

        System.Console.WriteLine("Number of Items " + testList.NumberOfItems());
        System.Console.WriteLine("Display Items " + testList.DisplayItems());
        System.Console.WriteLine("10 is Present " + testList.IsPresent(10));
        System.Console.WriteLine("20 is Present " + testList.IsPresent(20));
        System.Console.WriteLine("30 is Present " + testList.IsPresent(30));
        System.Console.WriteLine("40 is Present " + testList.IsPresent(40));
        System.Console.WriteLine("50 is Present " + testList.IsPresent(50));
        System.Console.WriteLine("60 is Present " + testList.IsPresent(60));
        System.Console.WriteLine(testList.RemoveItem(10));






        System.Console.ReadLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

But the RemoveItem method giving me grief, could someone please possibly help me out? Thank you.

This is the bit of code giving me a problem-

```
    public void RemoveItem(int item)
    {
        Link current = list;
        Link previous = null;

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.Data == item)
            {
                if (previous != null)
                {

                    previous.Next = current.Next;
                    current = current.Next;

                }


                else
                {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.Next;
                    list = current;
                }
            }
            else
                previous = current;
               current= current.Next;
        }

    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You have a problem at

```
 System.Console.WriteLine(testList.RemoveItem(10));
```

since `RemoveItem` doesn't return any value:

```
 // void - the method doesn't return any value
 public void RemoveItem(int item) 
 {
   ...
 }
```

you can't print it out. Just call `RemoveItem` and do not `WriteLine`:

```
 testList.RemoveItem(10);
```

A better approach is to re-design `RemoveItem` and let it return `bool` (if item has been removed):

```
 public bool RemoveItem(int item) {
   ... 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much kind sir. I apologise for my stupid idiotic mistake. Thank you. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You've touched on your own problem. You are trying to print the output of `RemoveItem` on this line:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(testList.RemoveItem(10));
```

But `RemoveItem` doesn't *have* any output since it has a return value of `void`. But `void` doesn't mean "ignore this method". `Console.WriteLine` still expects a value, but the value it is given isn't something it can do anything with, hence the error.

You need to either remove the print call:

```
RemoveItem(10);
System.Console.Writeline("10 removed.");
```

Or change `RemoveItem` to return a value:

```
public bool RemoveItem(int item)
{
    ...
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much kind sir. I apologise for my stupid idiotic mistake. Thank you. Greatly appreciated.